# Performance consistently better in the evening?

Tags: training

This has been on the back of my mind for ~5 years after I started riding consistently but never got around to asking it. I always get faster average speed/power (Strava estimate, I don't have a power meter) in the evening compared to morning or noon. I've verified this over many, many rides. Why is this?

Comment: What are your eating and drinking habits? You'll be faster with some carbs on board and not in the slightest dehydrated. Do you live somewhere where the wind changes predictably over the course of the day (common near the sea)? Are you comparing exactly the same route in the same direction? What about traffic?

Comment: In my experience it’s because I am excited to get home from work and vice Versa in the morning

Comment: Back when I'd cycle to and from work I'd usually do better in the morning.

Comment: Early signs of vampirism.

Comment: What are the elevations of your home and work ?  an average of 1% gradient won't be visible but could be altering your times.  Same goes for prevailing weather conditions, if your area has a prevailing wind direction that blows from work toward home more often.

Comment: Do you get up and ride soon after?  Or do you get up, do stuff, and then ride ?

Comment: If you are commuting, might be more to do with work than cycling.  :)  However, like many words spoken in jest, maybe motivation does have something to do with it.

Comment: I often get a better time in the evening or a Sunday afternoon, I can gain 10 minutes just down to the traffic being less and the lights in my favour. After experimental tests I've found the worst possible time to go riding is when the schools kick all the kids out. This is dependent on location.

Comment: Another factor:  warmer air is less dense, meaning you'll have slightly lower air resistance to overcome in the evening, as it's generally warmer in the evening than it is in the morning.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have noticed a definite difference based on humidity (and presumably wind resistance).  I'd often take a route that dipped into creek valleys, and on hazy days I could even feel the greater resistance (plus note it on my speedometer) as I went into a valley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very normal, but not particularly well understood phenomenon.

If you google *"cycling higher power output in evening"* you will find several published scientific papers showing improved performance in the evening.

Comment: I have just read briefly the top result in Google and it seems flawed unless I'm not reading it correctly. A quote from the top result " A
greater mean power output occurred in the evening 210.56 + 55.51 (W) compared to 201.83 + 58.09 (W) in the morning. " that's backwards for a start. The whole paper can be read here https://www.biologyofexercise.com/images/issues/42.pdf if anyone is interested

Comment: what's backwards?  210 is indeed greater than 201

Comment: My bad, had a feeling i was reading it wrong :doh: more coffee needed